# readOnly MobileDatePicker doesn't work in Material UI v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

The `readOnly` flag for MUI MobileDatePicker doesn't work. The API has no effect on `onClick` functionality. The only workaround is to use disabled flag. However, we use both `readOnly` and disabled functionalities for different uses cases. Any help appreciated.

```
<MobileDatePicker
  label="Date mobile"
  disableOpenPicker
  inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
  value={value}
  readOnly
  onChange={handleChange}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField {...params} InputProps={{ readOnly: true }} />
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the `TextField` inside is read-only but the picker is not and you can open the picker by clicking the `TextField`. An easy workaround is to always set the `open` state to `false` to prevent the picker from being opened:

```
<MobileDatePicker readOnly open={false}
```

If you need to change the `readonly` value dynamically:

```
function EnhancedMobileDatePicker(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const { readOnly } = props;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // do not auto open picker after setting readOnly to false
    if (!readOnly) setOpen(false);
  }, [readOnly]);

  return (
    <MobileDatePicker
      {...props}
      readOnly={readOnly}
      open={readOnly ? false : open}
      onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
      onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: The above solution works for case where the picker is always disabled. I am passing a prop to identify if the picker is disabled. The above solution fails when the value is passed as true i.e. the date picker popup is always open and doesn't close.

Comment: @Yash so you want a dynamic `readonly` for your `DatePicker`?

Comment: @Yash see my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Is there a way around? For testing purposes, we use something like below. But just want to know if there is an actual solution around.

Comment: `{props.isEditable ?
<MobileDatePicker
    label='Date Selector'
    ....
/>
:
<MobileDatePicker
    label='Date Selector'
    readOnly
    open={false}
    ....
/>
}`

Comment: @Yash see my updated answer and codesandbox for a workaround for dynamic value. Does that work for you?

Comment: yes this might be considered as a solution, but then my form has close to 10 date fields and this will add too many states and too many re-renders to the form. Again, we have to consider isolated re-render and using a single state to manage all open status i.e. as an array or object. But just wondering why MaterialUI haven't thought of this as an issue.

Comment: @Yash it's not a problem even with 20 fields if you can isolate the component into a wrapper to prevent re-rendering the whole form. See my updated codesandbox to see how it's done. About the behavior, I believe it's a bug, you should file an issue on the MUI repo and wait for them to fix it.

Comment: I believe we can live with this for now. Thanks.